# Window.focus() not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have the below javascript code which opens a url in new tab if it is not already opened. But if it is already opened it just bring it to focus. This code is working fine in Chrome. But not in IE11. All the url are in intranet zone.

```
 var loadingTonl;
 $('#tonlsg').click(function(){
 var url="<Some url>";
 if(loadingTonl == undefined || loadingTonl.closed)
    loadingTonl = window.open(url,'tonlFrame');
 else
    loadingTonl.focus();
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.open()` in IE returns `NULL` if **Protected Mode** is **Enabled**

This option can be toggled by unchecking "Enable Protedcted Mode" in Tools -> Internet Options -> Security: "Security level for this zone".

You will not face this issue if the web page is accessed from a proper website(from Internet).